# dehumidifier setting and humidity setting(April air unit) What is appropriate?

Tags: humidity

I can't find the right setting for the upstairs vs. the basement for the humidifier on my furnace. I have the dehumidifier in basement on 50%.

Comment: `I can't find the right setting` ....  what does this mean? ..... what determines a `right setting`?

Comment: Had the humidifier on 30% but after installing the dehumidifier in basement, it isn't enough

Comment: you keep using vague statements like `it isn't enough` ..... it is still unclear what the problem actually is ..... please describe clearly what you are trying to achieve and what is actually happening .... we are not mind readers

Comment: You're running a dehumidifier and a humidifier? When I run my furnace downstairs the air conditioner upstairs can't keep up. Do you see the flaw in the your logic?